# Copy method of string library doesn't work on my constructor

Tags: c++, oop

When I call in main the display function it doesn't output me the strings I've initialized my Object.

```
class Grupa{
    char indicativ;
    string team[4];
public:
    Grupa(char ind,string teams[4])
    {
        indicativ=ind;
        copy(team,team+4,teams);//here it doesn't copy the string correctly!
    }
void display()
{
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Grupa "<<indicativ<<":"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<". "<<team[i]<<endl;
    }
}

};
```

Comment: (1). `std::copy` is a part of `<algorithm>`, not `<string>`. (2) You are copying from empty-string-filled `team` to parameter `teams`

Answer (score 2):

Your copy goes in the wrong direction:

```
class Grupa{
    char indicativ;
    string team[4];
public:
    Grupa(char ind,string teams[4])
    {
        indicativ=ind;
        std::copy(teams,teams+4,team);
                              // ^ destination 
    }
};
```